# How to configure multiple SPI devices on Linux

Tags: linux, kernel, devices

I have an embedded Linux system (F&S PicoComA5) that has shipped with a pre-configured Linux Kernel + buildroot system.

By default, only one SPI device is pre-configured, appearing in the system as 
/dev/spi0.0

Now on my board, I have a second SPI devices, so I need to select another 'CS' line, and it should appear as
/dev/spi0.1

Where in the kernel or buildroot do I configure these parameters to make this second SPI device appear?

EDIT: in arch/arm/arm-mvf/arch-picocom.c, the board-specific init code, the SPI devices are initialized, I hope to find the way to make it work there!

Comment: According to the product info page, the board only has 1 SPI device. https://www.fs-net.de/de/produkte/picocom/picocoma5/

Comment: By default yes, but by using a GPIO pin as a second chip select, I feel confident an additional SPI device could be used.

Answer (score -1):

Configure SPI is possible by using ioctl call.

For example, to set SPI data transfer speed.
Use ioctl system call to configure SPI device

```
int Ioctl ( <spi_device_handle>, <command>,<value>)
```

Example setting speed to 2 MHz of SPI Interface,

```
Command = SPI_IOC_WR_MAX_SPEED_HZ 
int  spi_freq = 2000000;     // 2 MHz
Int ioctl (f_spi, SPI_IOC_WR_MAX_SPEED_HZ, &spi_freq);
```

The following video should be useful to you, [SPI in Embedded Linux - Quick Reference Guide](https://youtu.be/QTd4epkBBek).

Comment: Copying code directly and verbatim from a youtube video is never a good idea... at [7:00](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QTd4epkBBek&t=420), the code shown contains a error... which one is correct, is it `int Ioctl()` or `Int ioctl()`?